# Camel SEDA and VM endpoints not uses all threads

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following route...

```
<route id="VM01_spit_products">
    <from uri="direct:processXML" />
    <split>
        <method ref="CamelSplitOnKey" method="splitIntoBatches" /> 
        <to uri="vm:processXMLSplit" />
    </split>
</route>

<route id="VM01_processXML">
    <from uri="vm:processXMLSplit?concurrentConsumers=15" />
    <bean ref="Builder" method="createXMLFile" />
    <to uri="{{ChangeReceiver}}" />
</route>
```

I was expecting with the use of VM or SEDA to mean that if the spliter is producing 5 messages, then one of the 15 threads I have defined would pick up each of these messages. When I debug into the Builder class, I can see that the messages are being picked up sequentially.

I see the same if I an using VM or SEDA.

Can someone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Notes:

- Camel 2.6 due to JDK 1.5

---

New info.

I've added this code into my Builder.java

```
SedaEndpoint seda = (SedaEndpoint) camelContext.getEndpoint("seda:processXMLSplit");
int size = seda.getExchanges().size();
System.out.println("size ["+size+"]");
```

This prints a size of 0 each time.

This makes me think that the split isn't queuing up the messages as I expect.

Comment: Can you try using the same URI format as it is suggested in http://camel.apache.org/vm.html ->Same URI must be used for both producer and consumer . It mentions version lower than 2.3 but I see it reappeard in 2.9.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5261 Maybe this also affects your version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have defined your vm consumer to have 15 threads it doesn't affect how your Split is working. By default Split is working sequentially so you must configure your Split to use **parallelProcessing** in order to get the result you want. See further in [Splitter ParallelProcessing](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html). Note also @Itsallas comment that you might need your vm endpoint configured with the same parameters.